# Compress and remove original directory with limited storage

Tags: rm, zip, compression, storage

On my 3 TB external hard drive, I have a 2.7 TB directory containing relatively small files. I would like to compress this 2.7 TB directory and remove it to keep only the compressed version. The issue is that I do not have enough storage to first `zip` and then `rm` the non-zipped directory.

Is there a way around this problem or do I necessarily have to acquire more storage for the manipulation?

Comment: That may help: http://superuser.com/questions/656111/tar-bz2-compress-a-file-removing-uncompressed-original

Comment: Your title is misleading. Why do you want to compress if you want to remove it anyway? Or do you want to move+compress it to another drive?

Comment: @ott Given directory `d`, I would like to compress it into `d.zip` and then `rm -r d` but I don't have enough storage for that. Does it make sense? Sorry if the title is misleading. I welcome suggestions to improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try the `--remove-files` argument to tar. Say you want to compress everything on directory FOO, you would:
`tar -czf FooCompressed.tar.gz --remove-files FOO`

Arguments explained:

- c: create TAR
- z: compress using GZIP, you can switch to `-j` for BZIP2 or `-J` for LZMA(xz)
- f: output to file instead of of STDOUT
- remove-files: self explanatory

Comment: ** I said try because I don't know if the released space will be available on the fly.

Comment: For anyone who finds this like I did, the version of tar I used did release the space on the fly, so I was able to use the 6GB of free space I had on my SD card to convert an 11GB folder to the archive version (used bzip2 with -j, if it matters). At least until I hit 4GB because the SD card was FAT32 formatted, oops. But I was using `watch` on the available disk space and folder/archive sizes and it used/freed up around +/- 200 MB as it worked through the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If the largest file in the directory is less than 300GB (the amount of free space), the easiest option is to compress files individually rather than creating an archive; something like

```
find directory -type f \! -name '*.xz' -print0 | xargs -0 xz -9
```

will compress all non-compressed files in `directory` using `xz` at compression level 9. This will replace files one at a time with the corresponding compressed version, adding a `.xz` extension (so `foo.txt` becomes `foo.txt.xz`).

In fact, this can work even if the largest file is larger than the available free space, as long as you have enough files smaller than the available free space: start by compressing the smaller files, which will progressively free more and more space up, until (hopefully) you have enough free space to handle the largest file.

Comment: I got "File name too long" when I tried to do this. I think it is because too many files under the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I normally never make zip files, so I'm no expert, but it looks like `zip` by default just adds files to an archive, so something like (**untested** - contains an `rm` command = potentially **dangerous** - Test yourself before risking your data):

`for f in $(ls --sort=size --reverse); do zip -9 archive.zip $f; rm $f; done`

in the directory, could probably do it.

Comment: One safety valve I'd add would be to change `zip...; rm...` to `zip... && rm

Comment: @JeffSchaller - and never do `for f in $(ls whatever)` ...

Comment: @Henrik If I remember correctly, when adding files to an existing archive, `zip` creates a new archive alongside the old one — so when space is short this doesn't work.

Comment: @don_crissti using `for f in $(ls a)` is perfectly fine. If you feel uncertain you know what will be selected, then just do `for f in $(ls a); echo $f; done` first and see what is going to be acted on. I wouldn't use this is say, a cron job, but with human interaction, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for sake of posterity another way of doing this if wanted to use zip is -m flag

> -m     Move the specified files into the zip archive; actually, this deletes the target  directories/files
> after  making  the  specified zip archive. If a directory becomes empty after removal of the files,
> the directory is also removed. No deletions are done until zip  has  created  the  archive  without
> error.  This is useful for conserving disk space, but is potentially dangerous so it is recommended
> to use it in combination with -T to test the archive before removing all input files.

Comment: “No deletions are done ***until*** zip has created the archive without error.”  I believe that this means that this is just shorthand for ``zip && rm`` — i.e., it will fail, since the OP’s free space is too little to create the archive.  Do you have a reference that clearly says that this will work?

Answer (score 0):

add these bash functions to your ~/.bashrc:

```
xzd()  { find $1 -type f  \! -name '*.xz' -exec xz -9 {} \; ; }
xzdv() { find $1 -type f  \! -name '*.xz' -print -exec xz -9 {} \; ; }

uxzd() { find $1 -type f  -name '*.xz' -exec unxz -9 {} \; ; }
```

and then from the command line you can do:

```
mac@challenger:~/views$ du -sk HelloWorld/
236 HelloWorld/

mac@challenger:~/views$ xzd HelloWorld
mac@challenger:~/views$ du -sk HelloWorld
116 HelloWorld

mac@challenger:~/views$ uxzd HelloWorld
mac@challenger:~/views$ du -sk HelloWorld
236 HelloWorld
```

the xzdv is a more verbose form of the xzd, and echos each file as it is compressed

```
mac@challenger:~/views$ xzdv ./HelloWorld/
./HelloWorld/.cproject
./HelloWorld/src/helloworld.c
...
mac@challenger:~/views$
```

(Incorporated suggestions from the comments - thanks!!!)

Answer (score -1):

I successfully compress and decompress with the following 2 commands, it works with a lot of files under the folder:

```
for f in $(find /backup/test/ -type f  \! -name '*.xz'  -printf "%f\n"); do xz -9 $f; done

for f in $(find /backup/test/ -type f  -name '*.xz'  -printf "%f\n"); do unxz $f; done
```

Comment: use '-print' instead of 'printf "%f\n" : (-printf %f just prints file name, not the leading path). (using GNU find version 4.7.0 (findutils).  Also see alias answer next: